# Node.js: How to import/require a file, run its commands and access its updated variables like in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, require, code-translation

In python you can just have file1.py with a class called "class1" like this:

```
class class1:
    def __init_(self, var1, var2):
        self.var3 = var1
        self.var4 = var2
        
        self.callFunction(self.var3, self.var4)

    def callFunction(self, classVar1, classVar2):
        print(classVar1)
        print(classVar2)
    
    def anotherFunction(self, otherVar1, otherVar2):
        daString = otherVar1 + otherVar2
        return daString

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class1('passing var1', 'passing var2')
```

And we can import it in file2.py with:

```
from folder import file1
from folder.file1 import *
```

And we can then call file1.py class in file2.py and access literally everything in it, including *updated* self variables like this:

```
newThing = file1.class1('updated self var1', 'updated self var2')
# lets print our updated self vars from file1.py class

print(newThing.var3) # "updated self var1"
print(newThing.var4) # "updated self var2"

# lets call a function from file1.py's class and print result

result = newThing.anotherFunction('test', '123')
print(result) # test123
```

Pretty simple. Now my question is: how can this exact thing be done in node.js? My first failed attempt was this:

File1.js:

```
class Class1 {
    constructor(var1, var2) {
        this.cVar1 = var1;
        this.cVar2 = var2;
        this.extraThing = 'extra text';

        someFunction(this.cVar1, this.cVar2); // wont work, it doesnt recognize someFunction()
    }
    someFunction(passArg1, passArg2) {
        console.log(passArg1 + passArg2 + this.extraThing); // this.extraThing seems to be undefined, same with just extraThing
    }
}
module.exports = new Class1();
```

Loading File1.js in File2.js:

```
const importClass = require('File1.js');

module.exports = async function(var1, var2) {
    let classThing = new importClass(var1, var2); // will load, but unable to call a fnction inside of it

    let var3 = 'something';
    let var4 = 'else';

    classThing.someFunction(var3, var4); // wont work, cant access someFunction (its undefined)
}
```

And my second failed attempt was abandoning the Class idea and just doing `exports.Class1 = function ();` in File1.js which would probably be even worse for what I'm trying to do.

I'm new to node.js so there's a very high chance that I'm doing something completely stupid and I'm aware of it.. but I've been searching on the internet for a long time and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Is what I'm looking for (the equivalent to how its done in python) even possible in node.js?

Comment: You've asked a few related, but separate things here.  All answerable questions, but they probably should be broken out, for example: How do I access the methods and properties of the instance of a Javascript class?  and How do I import a class in commonJS syntax?  Or How do I import a class using ES module syntax?  And finally, what is scope in Javascript, and how does it work in classes?  Each of these questions probably deserves a separate post if you can't find the answers to them individually.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite the python code you provided to NodeJS — I'd do it like:

<sub>`folder/file1.js`</sub>

```js
class Class1 {
    constructor(arg1, arg2) {
        this.var3 = arg1;
        this.var4 = arg2;

        this.callFunction()
    }

    callFunction() {
        console.log(this.var3)
        console.log(this.var4)
    }

    anotherFunction(otherArg1, otherArg2) {
        const daString = otherArg1 + otherArg2;
        return daString
    }
}

if (require.main === module)
    new Class1("passing var1", "passing var2")

module.exports = Class1;
```

<sub>`file2.js`</sub>

```js
const file1_Class1 = require("./folder/file1.js");

const newThing = new file1_Class1("updated self var1", "updated self var2")

console.log(newThing.var3);
console.log(newThing.var4);

const result = newThing.anotherFunction("test", "123");
console.log(result);
```

which will give the exact same log result like in Python:

1- executing: `$ node file2.js`

> ```
> updated self var1
> updated self var2
> updated self var1
> updated self var2
> test123
> ```

2-  executing directly: `$ node folder/file1.js` (as *"main"*)

> ```
> updated self var1
> updated self var2
> ```

The updated values of the class **properties** are used within the Class itself by using `this`. I.e: `this.var3`, `this.callFunction()` etc, just like you would do in Python using `self`.

From an imported (*default*) Class you create an instance using the `new` keyword,
and than you use the variables and function methods using your instance name `newThing.var3`, `newThing.callFunction()` etc.

Comment: This worked great. However in the called method I have a async function and inside that async function, this.variables and this.methods aren't recognized. How can I access them?